# Eliminating Duplicate Id in partial view MVC 3 razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a page which adds dynamic partial views based on user interaction.Also the same partial view can be added as many times.Each partial view performs submit through JQuery and AJAX.What is the best way to avoid duplicates for Ids across the page.It is very important because JQuery functions uses the ID selector.Please provide me a solution.

### Partial View1

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function () {
        $("#MyButton1")
            .button()
            .click(function () {
                alert("MyButton1 clicked From MyForm1 ");
            });
    });
</script>
<div><p>MyForm1</p></div>
<form id="MyForm1" >
    <input id="MyButton1" type="button" value="buttonFromPartial1" />
 </form>
```

### Partial View2

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function () {
        $("#MyButton1")
            .button()
            .click(function () {
                alert("MyButton1 clicked From MyForm2 ");
            });
    });
</script>
<div><p>MyForm2</p></div>

<form id="MyForm2" >
    <input id="MyButton1" type="button" value="buttonFromPartial2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a helper or javascript code that generates a random id, in either server or client side.

**C# Function in the server side inside the view example:**

```
@function string GenerateId(string prefix)
{
return string.Format("{0}_{1}",prefix,Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
}
```

**Javascript function in the client side inside the view example:**

```
function generateId(string prefix) {
  return prefix + Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
             .toString(16)
             .substring(1);
};
```

Create inside the partial view a variable that contains the generated value and use it.

```
@var buttonId = GenerateId("button")
// buttonId = "button_85021948560128"
...
```

This way every partial view will generate its own unique ids.

Comment: thanks...this was the method i started with.I felt there would be some other solution in MVC since in ASP.net they handled it very neatly.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if it's still useful to you, but in Razor I use TemplateInfo to prefix my partial view IDs when I find the engine is creating duplicate IDs.

Usage:

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartialView", new MyModel(), new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "PrefixGoesHere" } })
```

This will produce an ID similar to this: YourPrefix_MyModelProperty.

Avoids a whole lot of unnecessary helper methods and javascript.

Comment: Now I'm happy I looked this question up! Thanks for the useful answer :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work out well for razor forms, it adds the prefix, but then your request payload turns out to be empty when you hit submit, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this, where you have N number of the same thing on the page, I think it's best stop replying on the id's and instead use relative logic.

In your case that would mean handling the click event of the submit button and applying your post logic to the form it is in.

You can use a jQuery selector that is not dependent on ID to do the binding.  See the code below that uses a class selector.

Sample HTML

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input class="buttonFromPartial" name="myButton" type="button"  />
</form>
<form name="myForm">
    <input class="buttonFromPartial" name="myButton" type="button"  />
</form>
```

Click handler

```
$("input.buttonFromPartial").click(function () {
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    //do your post logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But say i have 100 partial view(this is my case am treating every pages in my module as a partial view) i need to centralize every javascript in main page and that i have to load them in a single shot.Rather than loading as and when dynamically adding them when partial views are added

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example it add `TestBox` on button click  based on user need all text box with diffrent id . You should do something like this in your `PartialView` Code

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $("#AddControls").click(function () {
            count++;
            var elements = "<input type='text' id='txt" + count + "'class='required'/><br/></br>";
            $("#dynamicControldiv").append(elements);
            // $(".required").rules("add" + count, "required");
        });

        $("#btnDynamicSubmit").on("click", function () {
            var textlength = $("input[type='text']").attr("class", "required");
            for (var i = 1; i <= textlength.length; i++) {
                var id = $("#txt" + i).attr('id');
                var value = $("#txt" + i).attr('value');
                if (value == "") {
                    $("#txt" + i).attr("required", "required");
                }
            }
            var validation = $("#dynamicControlForm"); //Your form id.
            if (!validation.valid()) {
                $("input[type='text']").attr("required", "required");
                return false;
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

**View**

```
 <input type="button" name="CreateControl" value="AddControl" id="AddControls" />
    <form action="/" method="post" id="dynamicControlForm">
    <div id="dynamicControldiv">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="DynamicControl" id="btnDynamicSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```